# Python IO error

Tags: python, ipython, ioerror

Sounds really naive. I have noticed lot of answers but nothing really did help my case

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("aa_y_ss.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    allrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in allrows:
```

throws an error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

but the file is there in the directory

I have checked the current directory with:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

`C:\\Users\\ ....\\Documents\\IPython Notebooks`

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Is your file named 'file name '?

Comment: can you post the exact code which does not work?

Comment: I have just added it then comes a for loop in which I do some computations in the file, but the error is AT the line of the reading the file

Comment: Maybe (not sure if this can cause errors) you don't have file access as a regular user?

Comment: Just a few wild guesses: Is the case of the file name correct, or is the file's name e.g. "AA_Y_SS.CSV"? Also, does the file maybe have one of those "hidden" extensions, like "aa_y_ss.csv.xls"? Also, if you _create_ a file (`open('bla','w')`), does it go to that same directory?

Comment: @tobias_k I think Python on Windows gets around improperly-cased names transparently, as long as it's not an NTFS volume...

Comment: Given that you are using IPython, why don't you use `!dir *.csv` to list the csv files in the current directory *as Python sees them*?

Comment: You could try giving the complete path.

Comment: "AT the line of the reading the file": Does this mean the line that starts `allrows=` or the line that starts `with open(`?

Comment: I tried the complete path, does not work,@Dan :it starts with open(

Comment: @dmvianna:thank you!. I do not have to name the file with extension .csv like in R , so when I did {!dir *.csv} it appeared as .csv.csv

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your try renaming your file?
I had a similar issue and I did that. issue gone